# Android FATAL EXCEPTION ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse

Firstly, I am using Eclipse IDE. I was trying to make an app store. I do not know what happened but it worked before, now I get this error in LogCat.

```
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No               Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.appstore.GAMENAME }
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at     android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.servetech.appstore.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at         java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-02 13:26:39.750: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.servetech.appstore;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.appstore.GAMENAME");
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });

}



}
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.servetech.appstore"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.servetech.appstore.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".GameName"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.servetech.appstore.GAMENAME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

PS: I have noticed that I am starting Activity a bit differently than everyone else. Just to let you know I am learning from thenewboston tutorials. I hope that is not the problem. I can post the GameName class if required.

EDIT: Already solved this, so do not waste your time trying to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real package of GAMENAME is `com.servetech.appstore.GAMENAME` not `com.example.appstore.GAMENAME`. That's why Android cannot found the activity.

> android.content.**ActivityNotFound** Exception: **No               Activity found** to handle Intent

So

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.appstore.GAMENAME");
```

to

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.servetech.appstore.GAMENAME");
```

Comment: You are the first to answer so i guess it is fair to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to run class `"com.example.appstore.GAMENAME` but in manifest you got `packageName+.GameName`.
So instead of `Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.example.appstore.GAMENAME");` try `Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.servetech.appstore.GAMENAME");`

Answer (score 1):

Change Intent in activity to:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.servetech.appstore.GAMENAME");
```